# Sails-React : Access props from Parent Component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sails.js

I'm developing a web application using Sails and React. I'm trying to get all the users from my database. So, for getting all the user, I wrote the following code

**Sails UserController**

```
index : function(req,res){

    User.find()
        .then(function(users){

            renderTo(routes, req.wantsJSON, res, "/user" , {title: 'Users'}, {'users' : users});

        }).catch(function(err){
            return res.negotiate(err);

        });
}
```

Now, to receive the array of users, my React code is :

**React Code**

```
var React = require('react');
var http = require('http');
var UserList = require('./userList');

var user = React.createClass({

    render: function() {

        return ( <UserList {...this.props} /> );
    }

});

module.exports = user;
```

**UserList Component**

```
var React = require('react');

var userList = React.createClass({


    render: function() {
        var createUserRow = function(user){
            return (<tr key={user.id}>
                        <td>{user.id}</td>
                        <td>{user.firstName}</td>
                        <td>{user.lastName}</td>
                        <td>{user.email}</td>
                    </tr>);
        };

        return (
            <div>
                <table className="table table-stripped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        {this.props.users.map(createUserRow)}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }

});

module.exports = userList;
```

And I'm getting the response as expected..But it's coming like this :

[image]

So my question is, how do I pass the list of users to my `UserList Component`, which is available at the Parent Component as displayed in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, got the answer..All I have to do is, pass the spread attribute `(...this.props)` to React-Router's `RouteHandler` like this :

```
var App = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header/>
                <RouteHandler {...this.props}/>
            </div>
        );
    }

});
```

Hope this helps..if anyone facing the similar issue.